# python line separated values in a text when converted to list, adds "\n" to the elements in the list

Tags: python

I was astonished that a thing this simple has been troubling me. Below is the code

```
list = []
f = open("log.txt", "rb")  # log.txt file has line separated values, 


for i in f.readlines():
    for value in i.split(" "):
        list.append(value)

print list
```

The output is

```
['xx00', '\n', 'xx01in', '\n', 'xx01na', '\n', 'xx01oz', '\n', 'xx01uk', '\n']
```

How can I get rid of the new line i.e. '\n'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If line-separated means that there is only one value per line, you don't need `split()` at all:

```
with open('log.txt', 'rb') as f:
    mylist = map(str.strip, f)
```

In Python 3 wrap `map()` in a `list()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
list = []
f = open("log.txt", "rb")  # log.txt file has line separated values, 


for i in f.readlines():
    for value in i.strip().split(" "):
        list.append(value)

print list
```

`.strip()` removes trailing newlines. to be explicit you can use `.strip('\n')` or `.strip('\r\n')` in some cases.

you can read more about `.strip()` [here](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

**edit**

better way to do what you wanted:

```
with open("log.txt", 'rb') as f:
    mylist = [val for subl in [l.split(' ') for l in f.read().splitlines()] for val in subl]
```

for an answer which is much easier on the eyes, you can import itertools and use chain to flatten the list of lists, like @[Jon Clements example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12951160/1561176)

so it would look like this:

```
from itertools import chain
with open("log.txt", 'rb') as f:
    mylist = list(chain.from_iterable(l.split(' ') for l in f.read().splitlines()))
```

Comment: Your "better" way results in a list of lists, one for each line. The OP appears to be trying to create a flat list.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("log.txt", "rb") as f:
    mylist = f.read().splitlines()
```

Also, don't use `list` as a variable name, as it overshadows the python type `list()`.

Comment: good comment about the overshadowing. but your answer is only partial, OP wants to split the lines `.split(" ")` and add that to his list, not add the whole line.

Comment: thanks Joel, but this was was not removing the space after the entry.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this, is:

```
with open('log.txt') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        print line.split()
```

By using `split()` **without** an argument, the '\n''s automatically don't become a problem (as split or split(None) uses different rules for splitting).

Or, more concisely:

```
from itertools import chain
with open('log.txt') as fin:
    mylist = list(chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in fin))
```

Comment: this is using `itertools` but you didnt mention in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a bunch of lines with space separated values, and you just want a list of all the values without caring about where the line breaks were (which appears to be the case from your example, since you're always appending to the same list regardless of what line you're on), then don't bother looping over lines. Just read the whole file as a single string and call `split()` with no arguments; it will split the string on *any* sequence of one or more whitespace characters, including both spaces and newlines, with the result that none of the values will contain any whitespace:

```
with open('log.txt', 'rb') as f:
    values = f.read().split()
```